# Public methods in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I want to make a javascript class with methods which I can call within the class as well as outside of the class. I want to make a "public" method, if you will. I want `getTextAreaElement` and `appendTextArea` to be such methods.

I've shown a snippet of best code I could come up with so far. I've also tried defining the methods as prototypes as well as within the class (`this.func = ...`). But that only allowed me to call the method outside (`new Socket().appendTextArea("osgjr89");`) but *NOT* within the class itself! The code snippet below shows the exact opposite implementation where I can't call the method outside of the class but *can* call it within.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #Socket has no method 'appendTextArea'

socket.js:

```
function Socket() {
var socket;
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (window.WebSocket) {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9012/websocket");
    socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    socket.onopen = onopen;
    socket.onmessage = onmessage;
    socket.onerror = onerror;
    socket.onclose = onclose;
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support Web Socket.");
}

function getTextAreaElement() {
    return document.getElementById('responseText');
}

function appendTextArea(newData) {
    var el = getTextAreaElement();
    el.value = el.value + '\n' + newData + " :)";
}

function onopen(event) {
    getTextAreaElement().value = "Web Socket opened!"; 
}
/*[...]*/
}
```

main.js (loads after socket.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = new Socket();
s.appendTextArea("osgjr89"); // ERROR!
});
```

UPDATED socket.js:

```
function Socket() {
[...]
if (window.WebSocket) {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9012/websocket");
    socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    socket.onopen = this.onopen;
    socket.onmessage = this.onmessage;
    socket.onerror = this.onerror;
    socket.onclose = this.onclose;
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support Web Socket.");
}

this.getTextAreaElement = function() {
    return document.getElementById('responseText');
}

this.appendTextArea = function(newData) {
    var el = this.getTextAreaElement();
    el.value = el.value + '\n' + newData + " :)";
}

this.onopen = function(event) {
    this.getTextAreaElement().value = "Web Socket opened!";
}
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All public methods must be declared as properties, not variables/functions. So, you have to change stuff like this:

```
function getTextAreaElement() {
    return document.getElementById('responseText');
}
```

into

```
this.getTextAreaElement = function() {
    return document.getElementById('responseText');
}
```

Comment: It seems we're getting closer to get it to work, but now the `onopen` callback isn't being fired (the server gets the connection and responds normally). I've updated the question with the modified socket.js code. Chrome reports no errors in JS.

Comment: You have to define `this.onopen` *before* you use it at `socket.onopen = this.onopen;`.

Comment: Oh, of course! Well, I got it to work now. I'll only ask for an advice now. To call other methods within a method I had to store the `Socket`'s `this` in one of its properties (i.e. `var socketThis = this;`), and then I called the method through that property (i.e. `this.func...(event){ socketThis.otherFunc(); }`). Is that the "right" way to do that, or do you recommend some other method?

Answer (score 2):

If you do `this.func = function() {}`, you can call the function inside the Constructor (`Socket` in your case)  using `this.func()` as well as outside using:

```
var s = new Socket();
s.func();
```